# How do I configure web.config to 301 redirect all index.php request to default homepage?

Tags: iis, web-config

I have clients' websites on a windows server running IIS. Some of my clients' previous websites had urls indexed that included index.php/varying_path_parameters

What I am trying to figure out is how to modify the web.config file such that any request to the index.php file is redirect to the main domain. I have a redirect to add a trailing slash to any url, but I am not sure how to modify this to target ANY request that includes .php

So is a request comes in for www.abc.com/index.php/someDir/  I want to redirect it to www.abc.com (without the trailing slash)

As mentioned above I already have a web.config file, just not sure on the way to redirect to the primary domain

```
          <rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/" />
          </rule>
```

I am just hoping to redirect all .php requests to the main domain  (please note I could not add the https : // to the url in my message, but I need it redirected there.

Comment: could you tell us what is your exact requirement? do you want to remove slash or you just want to redirect all php page to the domain like [image](https://i.imgur.com/EkkxQbC.jpg)

Comment: "So if a request comes in for www.abc.com/index.php/someDir/ I want to redirect it to www.abc.com (without the trailing slash)"